# Questions with very few words

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

While searching some solution on the net I found out that some people ask questions with very few words, and yet stackoverflow permits it.

I thinks it's 1 or 2 sentences only. However when I do that it shows an error saying that I don't meet stackoverflow standards on asking questions. On SO, I always explain everything to make my whole sentences large enough that the system will permit it to be posted. But what if I just want to ask some questions to clarify something that does not need some large and detailed explanation?

Is this some kind of a bug? If not, will someone tell me how are they doing it?

Comment: If your question is simple enough to be asked in a few words just for clarification of something, I would type it into google instead. If you have already tried that without success, it's probably best to let us know inside your question as to point out the complexity of it.

Comment: Yeah i know that. But im just curious on how to do it.

Comment: What is the question you're trying to ask? Can you show us? There might be other factors contributing to it not being allowed.

Comment: To be or not to be? **That** is the question.

Comment: isnt that what the chat is for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to a flood of post with less quality (often related to new users that are not aware of the rules), there are some mechanisms active to lighten the load of the moderators. In some cases experienced users (measured by reputation) have less restrictions.

Unfortunately, sometimes good posts are filtered out by this.

For now, please try to elaborate a bit.

Comment: Ahm i remember when its my first time to ask a question here. I got a question on my mind but i cant explain it.. I forgot it now. well Thanks for your explanation..

Answer (score 1):

If you find your post explaining the problem/what you want is too short, try and remember to include *why* you are asking and *what* you have done and why that doesn't work. Knowing why you're doing it means on occasion (not always) there might be a better solution you hadn't considered at all. Knowing what doesn't work and why helps us understand your why as well, and also saves us from suggesting stuff you know (but we might not know) doesn't work.